# Get the same zoomlevel in OpenURL(http) as in Safari? (OpenURL view not zoomable)

Tags: iphone, safari, openurl, zooming

Same behavior on Iphone 3 and 4, both with OS 4.3.2.

I open URLs not in a UIWebview but externally, with openURL() --> Safari.

If I go to visiteksjo.se in the Safari app, I get a zoomed-out view, and I can double-tap or pinch to zoom in and out.

If I open the same URL with OpenURL from within my app, I get a heavily zoomed-in view and can't zoom out or in, I have to pan to read.

I've done nothing special to get a special view of that page. Does Safari and Safari-from-openURL pass different information to the web page server?

What steps can I take to get the same viewing behavior from my app as in the Safari app?

(It seems as if the in-app Safari call behaves like the mobile version of search.yahoo.com, while the Safari app behaves like the desktop version of the same page.)

ps. The app in question is called [Eksjö](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/eksjo/id435475192?mt=8) on App Store, if you want to confirm the differences in behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution has been found, and I must conclude that openURL() has different behavior from opening the url in Safari in IOS, ie. missing feature or bug.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property `Scales Page To Fit` to true in Interface Builder of your UIWebview.
or via code:

```
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Where webView is either the IBOutlet or property for you webview.